# Reading user environment variables by os.environ

Tags: python-2.7, system-variable

I have a setup script (not mine) which reads a certain system variable. I tried setting this in two ways:

- Going to control panel > User Accounts > Change my environment variables
- In command line: *setx myvar myvalue*

I set it as user variables, since i don't have the rights to set system variables. If i open a new command line window and type *set*, my variable shows there correctly.

However, if i start python and run the following script, i don't see my variable:

```
import os
print os.environ
```

I am using windows 10 and python 2.7. Modifying the code to get the variable is not possible since it is code from an external library.

Comment: have you tried to start python in the command where it shows with `SET` ? because it should (and it does) be activated, what you're doing is OK. Worst case: logoff & logon to be sure all env. variables are propagated to all processes (but it's not necessary with `SETX`)

Comment: Logoff and Logon did the trick. Thank you